# Help me understand what is being asked for in this proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I got a question, for a number theory assignment. But I don't understand what it's saying at all; here it is:

Fix $n>1 $ and for a prime $p$ , define $r(p)$ as the unique integer s.t $2^{r(p)} \leq 2n <2^{r(p)+1}$. Show that the exponent of $p$ in $n!$ is $\sum_i^{r(p)}[\tfrac{n}{p_i}]$ where [] denotes the integer part.

I have some specific questions, but I understand so poorly what this question is saying, that I will not be asking enough. So, please add more detail to help me understand, more than, just what I'm asking. But, here's a few of my specific questions:

1) What is meant by "the exponent of $p$ in $n!$"?

2) Does answering the question have something to do with using the giveninequalities in order to make an inequality for $n!$?

3) There was explicit dependence stated for $p$ in $r(p)$. So, how do you extract any information about it?

Comment: 1) Take, say,  $n=4$. Then $n!=24$. The exponent of $p=2$ in $n!$ is the largest integer $e$ with $2^e\mid 24$. 2) There is a formula for $e$, not an inequality. It is called Legendre formula. You can find it with proof here on this site.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by point 3, but at least as it is given here $r(p)$ does not depend on $p$. I strongly assume that the real definition is $p^{r(p)} \le n < p^{r(p)+1}$ and you mistyped/misrememebered.

Comment: @Ingix no what I wrote is word for word what my lecturer did....could have been a typo though because I didn't think it made any sense either .